# Prove that if $A=A^2$, and $0\ne \bar{v}\in \text{Col} A$. then $\bar{v}$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A=A^2$ for $A\in \Bbb{M}_{n\times n}^{(\Bbb{R})} \ ,$ and $0\ne \bar{v}\in \text{Col} (A)$. then $\bar{v}$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, $v=Ax$ for some $x\in\Bbb R^n$. Now, $Av=A(Ax)=A^2x=Ax=v$. Since, $v\not=0$, we can say $v$ is an eigen-vector of $A$ corresponding to eigen-value $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, $0=A-A^2=(I-A)A$, so $(I-A)x=0$, or $x=Ax$, if $x$ is a column of $A$. Hence every nonzero column of $A$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with eigenvalue $1$, and so is any nonzero $\bar v\in \mathrm{Col}(A).$